# Problem deploying ASP.NET CORE 3.1 MVC app to azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

The main problem is the database. I have a local database created with Microsoft SQL Managment Studio and is the one I want my app to use as I have a register/login/credential system. I have created a SQL Server in azure with its own database with the idea of just copying the data from the local database to the new one. I have also created an app service plan and an app service. I have downloaded its publishing profile to use it on the upload. Then I edit its settings and add the

```
Server=tcp:csptest06.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=csptestDB06;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=JoseAdmin;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

on both the default connection and entity framework inmigration, then just publish it. At first it couldnt connect because I didnt add my ip but after that it just gave me this error:

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Error durante la ejecución del script de la base de datos. El error ocurrió entre las siguientes líneas del script: "326" y "342". El registro detallado podría tener más información acerca del error. El comando comenzaba con lo siguiente:
"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHisto"
 There is already an object named 'TUsers' in the database. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Obtenga más información en: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.)
Failed to publish the database. This can happen if the remote database cannot run the script. Try modifying the database scripts, or disabling database publishing in the Package/Publish Web properties page. If the script failed due to database tables already exist, try dropping existing database objects before creating new ones. For more information on doing these options from Visual Studio, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179181.
Error details:
Error durante la ejecución del script de la base de datos. El error ocurrió entre las siguientes líneas del script: "326" y "342". El registro detallado podría tener más información acerca del error. El comando comenzaba con lo siguiente:
"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHisto"
 There is already an object named 'TUsers' in the database. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Obtenga más información en: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.
There is already an object named 'TUsers' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DBStatementInfo.Execute(DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Int32 timeout)    CSP0308     0
```

Any idea on how to fix this? im relatively new to programming so please dont fear on going step by step on your ideas

Comment: `There is already an object named 'TUsers' in the database.`, It gives this error.

Comment: yes, I realise that is indeed the error, what I dont understand is why is that an error on the first place. Is it uploading my database (the local one) to azure on the process? is it having troubles if thats the case? Do I have a second TUsers table that im not aware of and needs removing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it and managed to publish it successfully. If anyone is wondering this is how I did it:

Followed this video:[How to upload your local database to AZURE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXLQUn-IOGg)

From that on I connected from visual studio to the database hosted in azure. Deleted a migration I had that dupped all the tables and from there I copied the connection string and published it.